# httpd is not running on startup

Tags: apache, service, centos

Everything was going alright, no edits have been done on the configurations, suddenly the httpd stopped running on start up, and another service made by me as well.
one information that the hard disk reached his full space so I had to delete some files.
the result of `chkconfig --list` is

```
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

Answer (score 5):

If httpd fails to start up, you should be able to find an error message in the error-log (`/var/log/httpd/error_log` or wherever you have configured its errors to). Check what gets logged when you manually try to start the service (`"service httpd start"`) and get back with more information if you don't understand what it is trying to tell you.

Comment: `/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log` had the error message in my case.

Answer (score 4):

If hard disk was full that would be the first reason of apache service not starting. Did you try restarting `httpd` service after freeing up some sufficient disk space and please also check the `httpd` error logs in `/var/log/httpd/error.log`. I think the major problem would have been due to disk space got full.

Try to free up some log files also to free up some more space in `/var/log` directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem in log configuration:

```
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(1)Operation not permitted: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /usr/teste.localhost-error.log.
```

I Changed my log path, created the file into my path setted and it worked after restarting.